Unable to Connect to AMT on HP Z4 Workstation with MeshCommander Due to Unknown IP Address
I'm having trouble using MeshCommander to connect to the AMT in my HP Z4 Workstation because I don't know the IP address, and MeshCommander isn't finding anything. According to the HP Bios Simulator document, I can find the MAC Address of the AMT network adapter similar to the one presented on Page 7. I checked the BIOS of my HP Z4 G4 workstation and noted the MAC Address. Since the same machine has a Linux OS installed, I checked the network interfaces and found the one with the same MAC Address.
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether [SAME_MAC_ADDRESS_AS_SHOWN_IN_THE_BIOS]  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 415  bytes 52182 (50.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14  bytes 1172 (1.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0x94500000-94520000

The issue is that the AMT network adapter does not seem to be getting an IP address. Here are the steps I've taken:

Used the command show arp | grep 84 in the EdgeRouter-X shell, but it didn't return any results. (The MAC address starts with "84")
Checked the rear port of the machine, and the LED lights are blinking.
The switch also shows blinking lights.

The device does not show up in the router DHCP lease, and I'm unable to see it in the ARP table.
How can I troubleshoot to obtain the IP address for the AMT network adapter or figure out why it isn't getting one?

To troubleshoot obtaining the IP address for the AMT network adapter on your HP Z4 G4 Workstation, you can start by resetting the AMT password if necessary. This can be done through a CMOS reset, as detailed on page 92 of the HP Z4 G4 Maintenance and Service Manual.
Once the password issue is resolved, access the BIOS by pressing the ESC key during boot. If the "ME Setup (F6)" option is not visible, ensure that "Intel Active Management Technology (AMT)" is enabled first. Enabling AMT will require a reboot to make the option available.
In the BIOS, select the 'ME Setup' option to enter the MEBx BIOS. Here, you'll need to update the AMT password, which must include upper- and lower-case letters, at least one digit, and one special character (e.g., !, @, #, $). After updating the password, you can configure the AMT settings, including the hostname and DHCP settings.
Ensure that DHCP is enabled so that the AMT can obtain an IP address automatically. Presumably, you can set a static IP address for the AMT interface. Then from the options, choose "Activate Network Access" from the menu to enable remote access.
After configuring AMT, use MeshCommander to scan for the IP address. MeshCommander should be able to detect the AMT device if it has obtained an IP address.
